# Resize DockPanel based upon child width

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I'm experimenting with WPF layouts, and I'm confused on how to get something to work. I want my `DockPanel` to resize automagically based upon how big the labels turn out to be. Now, I've found out how to make the `Labels` themselves auto resize, but it doesn't change the width of the `StackPanel` or `DockPanel`.  Here's my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,687,340" Width="Auto" LastChildFill="False">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <Label Content="Job #"    Height="Auto" Margin="0,5" Name="label1" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <Label Content="Customer" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5" Name="label2" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <Label Content="Location" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5" Name="label3" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <Label Content="Crossing" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5" Name="label4" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <Label Content="Engineer" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5" Name="label5" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <Label Content="Probe #"  Height="Auto" Margin="0,5" Name="label6" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <Label Content="Default is totally awesome and cool so you can just tdeal with it" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5"  Name="lblJob"      Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" Width="Auto" />
            <Label Content="Default" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5"  Name="lblCustomer" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" Width="Auto" />
            <Label Content="Default" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5"   Name="lblLocation" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" Width="Auto" />
            <Label Content="Default" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5"  Name="lblCrossing" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" Width="Auto" />
            <Label Content="Default" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5"   Name="lblEngineer" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" Width="Auto" />
            <Label Content="Default" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5"  Name="lblProbe"    Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" Width="Auto" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have the feeling that I'm missing something super silly, but maybe a fresh pair of eyes will be useful. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm attempting?

Comment: I'm confused. Just copying your code I can see if I change any of the `Label`'s content, the panel's do stretch out. Firstly since you have a custom `Style` anyways on your `Label`'s do your repeated property setting in the Style itself as default setter's. Next why do you have a Right and Bottom margin of 687,340 on your DockPanel. Also Your DockPanel currently will be stretched to fit the size of it's parent `Grid`, if you do not want that set `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` or so.

Comment: Finally, `Label`'s in WPF aren't the simplest form of text display control. Be sure to know if you "really" need them as 90% of the time you can get away with just a `TextBlock`

Comment: @Viv: Thanks so very much. The `Margin` setting on the `DockPanel` was what was preventing the resize. I'll look into the `TextBlock`/`Label` thing.

Comment: Just to clarify, it wasn't "preventing" the resize, you just were not able to see it since the entire control was outside the visible region, If you stretched the window wide enough you'd see it fine. If you're learning WPF layouts and xaml, start writing xaml code by hand. My Wild guess is this was generated by VS / Blend and they are great for quick lookup's but to "really" learn the language, start getting your hands dirty with some manual typing. Would be immensely beneficial in the long run.

Comment: @Viv: Yeah, I figured that was what was happening. I've done a fair share of typing out some of the XAML. But, I'm getting the hang of it.